# Hive schematool Command error org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Unknown version specified fo r initialization: 3.1.0

Tags: hadoop, hive

i install Hadoop in windows 10 and I have one site in IIS accounts.tax.gov.ir when i start Hadoop find one node with name accounts.tax.gov.ir.
but when i want run this command

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
```

i get this error

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/I:/apache-hive-3.1.2-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl
-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/I:/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j
12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Metastore connection URL:        jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create
=true
Metastore Connection Driver :    org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
Metastore connection User:       APP
Starting metastore schema initialization to 3.1.0
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Unknown version specified fo
r initialization: 3.1.0
Use --verbose for detailed stacktrace.
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

can anybody help me ?

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you running and are you sure Hive is capatible with it?

Comment: hadoop 3.2.1 and hive3.1.2

Comment: on tutorial say this version of hadoop and hive

Comment: Try a different Hive 3.x version https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-21623

Comment: this article haven't any solution for this problem and only say problem

Comment: Yes. It's an issue tracker for the version you're using and the same error. But did you not read "I had to use Hive 3.0"?

Answer (score 0):

you can delete any one class file which are redundant. Either form hive folder or hadoop folder. This will work